# Android - Usage of multiple activities

Tags: android

I need suggestion on the usage of multiple activities for my application. I want my application to handle about 20-30 physics/mathematical equations. Its like using a listview to allow the user to select the equation they wanna use.

Should I implement in a way such that a new activity opens up for each equation? In other words about 20-30 activities? Is there any other better alternative.

Comment: Fragments is the way to go!

Comment: Yup k... I'll read up on it... Thanks alot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single Activity, and switch out a Fragment for each of your equations.

So you will have an Activity, and in that layout, a space for the Fragment.  Then, you will use the FragmentManager to switch out Fragments when appropriate.

This will be a lot easier to manage than creating a ton of different Activities.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good tutorial on fragments [HERE](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) basically Fragments are parts of an activity that can be tacked on to an activity to make it do multiple things.  They are very useful if you are programming in Android 4.0 or higher and are much more efficient than the old style of using singular activities for everything.

Comment: You can use fragments with any Android OS, as they are supported using the SupportLibrary.